# the ability to save the game (using localStorage) and after reload the page continue the game

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm making a gem puzzle. And I have a save button. When you click it, the current state of the game is saved so that when the page is reloaded, the user can continue playing from the place where he saved. As I understand it, I have to save the table in localStorage. And when reloading the page, check if the localeStorage is empty. But how can I re-render game on page reload? When use json.stringify and json.parse, i have an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. When I remove json.stringify and json.parse it's an error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at LocalStorage is [object HTMLTableSectionElement]

```
let saveSession = false;
document.querySelector('.save-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  saveSession = true;
})
function start() {
  let button = document.getElementById('newGame');
  button.addEventListener('click', startNewGame, false );
  textMoves = document.getElementById('moves');
  table = document.getElementById('table');
  rows = 4;
  columns = 4;
  startNewGame();
}

function startNewGame() {
  let arrayOfNumbers = new Array();
  let arrayHasNumberBeenUsed;
  let randomNumber = 0;
  let count = 0;
  moves = 0;
  rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  columns = document.getElementById('columns').value;
  textMoves.innerHTML = moves;
  arrayForBoard = new Array(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    arrayForBoard[i] = new Array(columns);
  }
  arrayHasNumberBeenUsed = new Array( rows * columns );
  for (let i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++){
    arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[i] = 0;
  }
 for (let i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++){
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*rows * columns);
    if (arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[randomNumber] == 0) {
      arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[randomNumber] = 1;
      arrayOfNumbers.push(randomNumber);
    }else {
      i--;
    }
  }
  count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      arrayForBoard[i][j] = arrayOfNumbers[count];     
      count++;
    }
  }
  showTable();
}

function showTable() {
  for (let tr of document.querySelectorAll("#table tr")) {
    tr.remove();
  }
    let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(tbody);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('td');
      if (arrayForBoard[i][j] == 0) {
        cell.className = 'blank';
      } else {
        cell.className = 'tile';
        cell.draggable = true;
        cell.addEventListener('click', () => {
          moveThisTile(i, j);
        })
        cell.innerHTML =arrayForBoard[i][j];
      }
      tr.appendChild(cell);
    } 
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  } 
  if(saveSession) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentGame', JSON.stringify(tbody));
  }
};
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if(localStorage.getItem('currentGame') !== null) {
    const tbody = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'));
    document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(tbody);
  } else {
    start();
  }
}, false );
```

Comment: the problem is with `localStorage.setItem('currentGame', JSON.stringify(tbody));` JSON library isn't a magic fix-all to whole sale store full document elements and then just retrieve them so easily..

Answer (score 0):

When you save something into localStorage and using setItem(), you can retrieve it using getItem(). However one important thing here is that your local storage doesn't actually store the object as itself. What it stores is a JSON String.

So you need to do below while using the **localStorage.setItem()** function:

```
if(saveSession) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentGame', JSON.stringify(tbody));
  }
```

Now, when you need to retrieve this item from localStorage, you will have to parse that JSON string that you previously stored into localStorage you can use the localStorage.getItem() function in the following way:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     const tbody = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentGame'));
  }
```

If you ever need to check if your localStorage.setItem() has worked correctly or not, you can go to the 'Application' tab within your chrome dev tools and see the localStorage from there.

[image]

Comment: i have a [object HTMLTableSectionElement] and i have an error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. So i deleted JSON.stringify and JSON.parse: if(saveSession) {
    localStorage.setItem('currentGame', tbody);} window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     const tbody = localStorage.getItem('currentGame');document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(tbody);
  } and also have an error Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: It's very unclear trying to read from the comment. Can you update your question adding what you tried and what are the errors you received?

Comment: can you try to add JSON.stringify() but not JSON.parse() to see where the exact error is happening. If just stringify doesn't give an error then we can look at JSON.parse().

Comment: The point is that localStorage can only store strings, it cannot store JS objects. Therefore if you want to use localStorage, you will have to use JSON.stringify(). Please check if you are using the correct syntax for JSON.stringify() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: when I use only JSON.stringify() and not JSON.parse(), I have error - Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Comment: That error is happening due to something else, it is not related to JSON.stringify() or JSON.parse(). What the above error means is that you are trying to use appendChild() method on a parent element that is not a HTML DOM Node.

Comment: It can be due to any of these appendChild() functions that are present in your code: tr.appendChild(cell);
    } 
    tbody.appendChild(tr);

Comment: now i haven't any error, but now instead table I have in HTML  <table id="table">[object HTMLTableSectionElement]</table>

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I came across this question off of seeing another localStorage question and I'm gonna try to answer it now :D

> The problem is with `localStorage.setItem('currentGame', JSON.stringify(tbody));` JSON library isn't a magic fix-all to whole sale store full document elements and then just retrieve them so easily..

I'm gonna just store some data of the element to recreate it(`attributes`, `inneHTML`, `localName`)

What was left out? The elem's parent, any event listeners attached to the elem(functions have a lot of context and so does an elem's parent)

```js
//saves an element
function saveElem(name,elem){
  const item={attributes:[],localName:'',innerHTML:''}
  item.localName=elem.localName
  item.innerHTML=elem.innerHTML
  let {attributes}=item
  for(let i=0;i<elem.attributes.length;i++){
    attributes[i]=[elem.attributes[i].name, elem.attributes[i].value];
  }
  localStorage.setItem(name,JSON.stringify(item))
}

//loads an element
function loadElem(name){
  const item=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(name))
  const elem=document.createElement(item.localName)
  item.attributes.forEach(([type,value])=>{
    elem.setAttribute(type,value)
  })
  elem.innerHTML=item.innerHTML
  return elem
}


let saveSession = false;
document.querySelector('.save-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  saveSession = true;
})
function start() {
  let button = document.getElementById('newGame');
  button.addEventListener('click', startNewGame, false );
  textMoves = document.getElementById('moves');
  table = document.getElementById('table');
  rows = 4;
  columns = 4;
  startNewGame();
}

function startNewGame() {
  let arrayOfNumbers = new Array();
  let arrayHasNumberBeenUsed;
  let randomNumber = 0;
  let count = 0;
  moves = 0;
  rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
  columns = document.getElementById('columns').value;
  textMoves.innerHTML = moves;
  arrayForBoard = new Array(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    arrayForBoard[i] = new Array(columns);
  }
  arrayHasNumberBeenUsed = new Array( rows * columns );
  for (let i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++){
    arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[i] = 0;
  }
 for (let i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++){
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*rows * columns);
    if (arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[randomNumber] == 0) {
      arrayHasNumberBeenUsed[randomNumber] = 1;
      arrayOfNumbers.push(randomNumber);
    }else {
      i--;
    }
  }
  count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      arrayForBoard[i][j] = arrayOfNumbers[count];     
      count++;
    }
  }
  showTable();
}

function showTable() {
  for (let tr of document.querySelectorAll("#table tr")) {
    tr.remove();
  }
    let tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(tbody);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (let j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
      let cell = document.createElement('td');
      if (arrayForBoard[i][j] == 0) {
        cell.className = 'blank';
      } else {
        cell.className = 'tile';
        cell.draggable = true;
        cell.addEventListener('click', () => {
          moveThisTile(i, j);
        })
        cell.innerHTML =arrayForBoard[i][j];
      }
      tr.appendChild(cell);
    } 
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  } 
  if(saveSession) {
    saveElem('currentGame',tbody);
  }
};
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if(localStorage.getItem('currentGame') !== null) {
    const tbody = loadElem('currentGame');
    document.querySelector('#table').appendChild(tbody);
  } else {
    start();
  }
}, false );
```